# Need to display total price in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

just been trying to display my total price from a column in my footer row.
here is my code to try that but it doesnt seem to be even going through it when i put a break point in

```
Sub gvPayments_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        ' add the UnitPrice and QuantityTotal to the running total variables

        invoiceTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Total"))
    ElseIf e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
        e.Row.Cells(0).Text = "Total:"
        ' for the Footer, display the running totals
        e.Row.Cells(5).Text = invoiceTotal.ToString("c")

        e.Row.Cells(5).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right
        e.Row.Font.Bold = True
    End If
End Sub
```

If you need any more of my code, just ask!

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken the footer does not databind

Comment: Perhaps you should try this on DataBound

Comment: have you added ShowFooter="true" property of grid-view ??

Comment: The html of the grid might help

Comment: I'm not sure if the footer is divided into cells.

Comment: What is your `DataSource`? is it `DataSet` or `DataTable`?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a method that doesn't require handling any events.  It just uses a TemplateField and a couple different functions.  In your GridView, make the column like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
    <ItemTemplate><%#DisplayAndAddToTotal(Eval("Total").ToString(), "Total")%></ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate><%#GetTotal("Total")%></FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The second parameter to DisplayAndAddToTotal can be any string you want as long as you use the same string in GetTotal.  I usually just use the field name again though. Here are the two functions used, DisplayAndAddToTotal and GetTotal.  They use a Hashtable to store the totals so that it works with any number of columns you want to add up.  And they also work with counting the number of "True"s for a Boolean field.

```
Protected total As Hashtable = New Hashtable()

Protected Function DisplayAndAddToTotal(itemStr As String, type As String) As Double
    Dim item As Double

    If itemStr = "True" Then
        item = 1

    ElseIf Not Double.TryParse(itemStr, item) Then
        item = 0
    End If

    If total.ContainsKey(type) Then
        total(type) = Double.Parse(total(type).ToString()) + item
    Else
        total(type) = item
    End If

    Return item
End Function

Protected Function GetTotal(type As String) As Double
    Try
        Dim result As Double = Double.Parse(total(type).ToString())
        Return result
    Catch
        Return 0
    End Try
End Function
```